# Adding Unity Ads in flutter application

Tags: android, ios, flutter, unity-game-engine, ads

Hello stack overflow Community.

i am trying to set up unity Ads in my flutter application, but can't get it work.
I find only examples in the Internet which shows how to implement ads via buttons and click event but not how to show Ads for example without triggering an event.

I want a banner ad that's visible after app start and also an interstitial after app start
but it does not work how expected. The interstitial only pops up after a hot reload but not after entering the app manually over my test device.

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:kalendar/ad_helper.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:unity_ads_plugin/unity_ads_plugin.dart';

    void main() async {
      await  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

      await UnityAds.init(
        gameId: AdHelper.addUnitId,
        onComplete: () => print('Initialization Complete'),
        onFailed: (error, message) =>
            print('Initialization Failed: $error $message'),
      );

      await UnityAds.load(
        placementId: AdHelper.interstitialId,
        onComplete: (placementId) => print('Load Complete $placementId'),
        onFailed: (placementId, error, message) =>
            print('Load Failed $placementId: $error $message'),
      );

      await UnityBannerAd(
        placementId: AdHelper.bannerId,
        onLoad: (placementId) => print('Banner loaded: $placementId'),
        onClick: (placementId) => print('Banner clicked: $placementId'),
        onFailed: (placementId, error, message) =>
            print('Banner Ad $placementId failed: $error $message'),
      );

      await UnityAds.showVideoAd(
        placementId: AdHelper.interstitialId,
        onStart: (placementId) => print('Video Ad $placementId started'),
        onClick: (placementId) => print('Video Ad $placementId click'),
        onSkipped: (placementId) => print('Video Ad $placementId skipped'),
        onComplete: (placementId) =>
            print('Video Ad $placementId completed'),
        onFailed: (placementId, error, message) =>
            print('Video Ad $placementId failed: $error $message'),
      );
         runApp(MyApp());
    }

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Kalendar',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: PageViewDemo(),
    );
  }
}

class PageViewDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PageViewDemoState createState() => _PageViewDemoState();
}

class _PageViewDemoState extends State<PageViewDemo> {
  PageController _controller = PageController(
    initialPage: 0,
  );

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  final List images = [
  "https://google.com",
  "https://google.com",
  "https://google.com",
  "https://google.com",

  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: SizedBox.fromSize(
            size: const Size.fromHeight(648),
            child: PageView.builder(
              allowImplicitScrolling: true,
              controller: PageController(viewportFraction: 1),
              itemCount: images.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    vertical: 0,
                    horizontal: 0,
                  ),
                  child: Material(
                    elevation: 5,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(1),
                    child: Stack(
                      fit: StackFit.expand,
                      children: [
                        Image.network(
                          images[index],
                          fit: BoxFit.contain,
                        ),
                        DecoratedBox(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            gradient: LinearGradient(
                              begin: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
                              end: FractionalOffset.topCenter,
                              colors: [
                                const Color(0x00000000).withOpacity(0.0),
                                const Color(0xff000000).withOpacity(0.01),

                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}



class AdHelper {
  static String get addUnitId {
    if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
      return '4828341';
    }
    if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS) {
      return '4828340';
    }
    return '';
  }

  static String get bannerId {
    if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
      return 'Banner_Android';
    }
    if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS) {
      return 'Banner_iOS';
    }
    return '';
  }

  static String get interstitialId {
    if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
      return 'Interstitial_Android';
    }
    if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS) {
      return 'Interstitial_iOS';
    }
    return '';
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

At first create a dart file 'unityAds.dart' and the code of 'unityAds.dart' is:

```dart
    import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
    import 'package:unity_ads_plugin/unity_ads_plugin.dart';
    
    class AdManager {
    
      static Future<void> loadUnityIntAd() async {
        await UnityAds.load(
          placementId: AdHelper.interstitialId,
          onComplete: (placementId) => print('Load Complete $placementId'),
          onFailed: (placementId, error, message) =>
              print('Load Failed $placementId: $error $message'),
        );
      }
    
      static Future<void> showIntAd() async {
        UnityAds.showVideoAd(
            placementId: AdHelper.interstitialId,
            onStart: (placementId) => print('Video Ad $placementId started'),
            onClick: (placementId) => print('Video Ad $placementId click'),
            onSkipped: (placementId) => print('Video Ad $placementId skipped'),
            onComplete: (placementId) async {
              await loadUnityIntAd();
            },
            onFailed: (placementId, error, message) async {
              await loadUnityIntAd();
            });
      }
    
      static Future<void> loadUnityRewardedAd() async {
        await UnityAds.load(
          placementId: AdHelper.rewardedId,
          onComplete: (placementId) => print('Load Complete $placementId'),
          onFailed: (placementId, error, message) =>
              print('Load Failed $placementId: $error $message'),
        );
      }
    
      static Future<void> showRewardedAd() async {
        UnityAds.showVideoAd(
            placementId: AdHelper.rewardedId,
            onStart: (placementId) => print('Video Ad $placementId started'),
            onClick: (placementId) => print('Video Ad $placementId click'),
            onSkipped: (placementId) => print('Video Ad $placementId skipped'),
            onComplete: (placementId) async {
              await loadUnityRewardedAd();
            },
            onFailed: (placementId, error, message) async {
              await loadUnityRewardedAd();
            });
      }
    }
    
    class AdHelper {
      static String get addUnitId {
        if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
          return '4994515';
        }
        if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS) {
          return '4994514';
        }
        return '';
      }
    
      static String get bannerId {
        if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
          return 'Banner_Android';
        }
        if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS) {
          return 'Banner_iOS';
        }
        return '';
      }
    
      static String get interstitialId {
        if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
          return 'Interstitial_Android';
        }
        if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS) {
          return 'Interstitial_iOS';
        }
        return '';
      }
    
    
      static String get rewardedId {
        if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
          return 'Rewarded_Android';
        }
        if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS) {
          return 'Rewarded_iOS';
        }
        return '';
      }
    }
```

Now you add the code on 'main.dart' :

```dart
import 'package:demo_01/unityAds.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:unity_ads_plugin/unity_ads_plugin.dart';

Future<void> main() async {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await UnityAds.init(
    // gameId: '5041608',
    gameId: AdHelper.addUnitId,
    onComplete: () => print('Initialization Complete'),
    onFailed: (error, message) =>
        print('Initialization Failed: $error $message'),
  );

 

  runApp(MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: const MyLogin(),
    routes: {
      'login': (context) => const MyLogin(),
    },
  ));
}
```

now, where you can implement add:

```dart
....

class _MyLoginState extends State<MyLogin> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) async {
      await AdManager.loadUnityIntAd();
      await AdManager.loadUnityRewardedAd();
    });
  }

....
}
```

Now you add this code on the onTap option:

```dart
 onTap: () async {
     await AdManager.showRewardedAd();
 }
```